# How to install apache drill on already running EMR cluster on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, apache-drill

I have a running EMR cluster that is persistent.  I dont want to tear down.

How do I install apache drill on already running EMR cluster on aws?

Answer (score 1):

There's a ruby script provided on the AWS Github https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/drill/setup_drill which looks like it *should* work, assuming you have ruby installed first. I don't see any reason why it couldn't run on an existing cluster. EMR runs bootstrap scripts after all the selected EMR components are installed, hadoop user created and config settings applied. Of course you'd test this on a new cluster so you don't break your persistent one.

The script needs to run on every node, so you can either scp or copy it to s3 then to each node with the aws cli, or use what @fmcmac suggested. I see on [line 38](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/6065841329f81d00e402df909bd69fff9af6e62e/drill/setup_drill#L38) that it is aware if the current node is the master so it is intelligent enough to install correctly.

It looks a few years since updated so you'd need to check the versions & dependency versions it is installing, and probably make some adjustments. It looks to be trying to get apache-drill-1.0.0.tar.gz from http://getdrill.org/drill/download  which should currently be v1.12.0 from the newer site https://drill.apache.org/download/ so at least that part needs to change. It also installs Zookeeper to run Drill, so check if you are already running Zookeeper as Drill will need to install as a new application in there if zookeeper is already there, you might experience issues if you try installing over the top, version compatibility is something to double check.

As an aside, EMR clusters are made to be torn down, bootstrap scripts & cluster configuration, and "steps" make that easy. Boot up, run job, tear down. It's cheaper that way. "Clusters are cattle, not pets". Even if you need it up for analysts to work on there's certainly times when it's not being used, costing you money.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have SSM installed you can use ssm.send_command (send the command to all nodes) to call an S3 script which installs and starts drill on a running EMR cluster.

There is an example of this here: https://gist.github.com/fmcmac/a35738376d111fdca45057bd0fb4c79e